# How to get 0 and 1 pixel after using LBP in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to execute local binary pattern in MATLAB.  LBP is working correctly but my problem with the result cause I want to get these zeros and ones when LBP is completely finished  and put all 0 and 1 to row vector

I tried to put all 0 and 1 to array but 8 times will put all 0 and 1 to array cause of for loop.
my image that I used is 256x256 that is mean I should get 256 0 and 1 but now I get 2048 if we divide 2048 by 8 we'll get 256 that is mean 8 times will put 0and1 to C array
I hope is more clear now

here is my code ::::

```
C=[];   %%% this array collect all zeros and ones 
for i=2:r-1
    for j=2:c-1
        if x(i,j)>x(i-1,j-1)
            arr(1,1)=0;
        else
            arr(1,1)=1; 
        end
         if x(i,j)>x(i-1,j)
            arr(1,2)=0;
        else
            arr(1,2)=1; 
        end 
        if x(i,j)>x(i-1,j+1)
            arr(1,3)=0;
        else
            arr(1,3)=1; 
        end
        if x(i,j)>x(i,j+1)
            arr(1,4)=0;
        else
            arr(1,4)=1; 
                end
                if x(i,j)>x(i+1,j+1)
            arr(1,5)=0;
        else
            arr(1,5)=1; 
                end
                 if x(i,j)>x(i+1,j)
            arr(1,6)=0;
        else
            arr(1,6)=1; 
                end
             if x(i,j)>x(i+1,j-1)
            arr(1,7)=0;
        else
            arr(1,7)=1; 
             end
             if x(i,j)>x(i,j-1)
            arr(1,8)=0;
           else
            arr(1,8)=1; 
             end

             %Convert Binary to Dec
        newimg(i,j)=sum(arr.*2.^(numel(arr)-1:-1:0));  


    end


C=[C arr];   %%  I think my problem with this line to putting zeros and one to C array

end

C
```

Comment: You can always *edit* your original question... and I am still confused by it but I think someone else may be able to help you...

Comment: ok but if you see my code before second end loop I wrote note that my problem with adding values to C array

Comment: I attempted an answer, we'll see if I understood :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the binary sequences for *all* of the pixels into `C`, place the statement within the two loops as follows:

```
C=zeros(8,254*254);   %%% this array collect all zeros and ones 
for i=2:r-1
    for j=2:c-1

     % ... if conditions here...

        %Convert Binary to Dec
        newimg(i,j)=sum(arr.*2.^(numel(arr)-1:-1:0));  


       C(:,j-1+(i-2)*254) = arr(:);

    end    
end
```

Note that `C` will *not* be 256 x 256 but 254 x 254 (look at the range of the loops).

I set it up so that `C` stores the data column-wise, one column per pixel

Comment: I changed 254 to 1    C(:,j+(i-1)*-1) = arr(:); so I get C row vector 1by256 
but I don't know it's right or not what do you think

Comment: @dlogold I don't fully understand what you are trying to do... in any case my answer generates a 8 x 64516  array. If you perform only one of the loops you'll get a 8 x 254 array. The change you proposed on the other hand does not make so much sense to me....